# MySQL query to order by condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

a) master_car

- car_id
- car_name

b) running_car

- running_car_id
- car_id [FOREIGN KEY of master_car]
- date

c) favorite_car

- favorite_id
- car_id
- user_id

Running car is an instance of master car date wise. So, example dataset:

**master_car**:

```
car_id - car_name
1 - Mercedes C Class
2 - Audi
3 - Volkswagen
```

**running_car**:

```
running_car_id - car_id - date
1 - 1 - 9 sep 2015
2 - 1 - 10 sep 2015
3 - 1 - 11 sep 2015
4 - 1 - 12 sep 2015
5 - 2 - 10 sep 2015
6 - 2 - 11 sep 2015
7 - 3 - 10 sep 2015
8 - 3 - 10 sep 2015
```

User can mark a car as **favourite**

```
favourite_id - car_id - user_id
1 - 2 - 1
2 - 1 - 2
```

When user logs in, he needs to see all the running cars. But first sorted by his favourite cars and then other cars.

For ex. if user with user_id - 1 logs in, he needs to see the following result:

```
running_car_id - car_id - date
5 - 2 - 10 sep 2015
6 - 2 - 11 sep 2015
1 - 1 - 9 sep 2015
2 - 1 - 10 sep 2015
3 - 1 - 11 sep 2015
4 - 1 - 12 sep 2015
7 - 3 - 10 sep 2015
8 - 3 - 10 sep 2015
```

What would be the query to get results ordered as per users favourite?

Comment: `left join` to `favourite`. Sort on `case when favourite_id is not null then 1 else 2 end` or maybe just sort on `favourite_id desc`. Nulls probably sort low but I don't know all of MySQL's options for that.

Comment: You might consider storing favourites and runnings in the same place

Comment: @Strawberry - how to store it together? It should be user specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want but this should cover most of it:

```
select r.running_id, r.car_id, r.date
from
    running_car r
    --inner join master_car m /* use this if you want to grab the name */
        --on m.car_id = r.car_id
    left outer join favourite_car f
        on f.car_id = r.car_id and f.user_id = <user_id>
order by
    case when f.favourite_id is not null then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: this one looks really good. I am testing it and will select if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You're ordering as per favourite_id, then date, is that correct? If so, a query like this should work. It joins running_car to the favourite_car table and `Left Joins` to select only the cars the user has favourited. Then, it order cars by favourited, then not favourited. I'm not sure how you're querying for current user, so I'll leave that for you to insert.

```
Select R.*
From running_car R
Left Join favourite_car F on R.car_id = F.car_id and U.(current user_id) = F.user_id
Order by
    (case when F.favourite_id is not null then 1 else 2 end), date
```

Comment: You're not considering `user_id` at all. I would presume that multiple users can have the same favorite car. At that point your query would return it multiple times.